# pointer shared between two threads without mutex

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

Will sharing a global pointer(without any synchronization) between two thread (one write and other reads) lead to situation where the 1st thread has written the first 4bytes (of the 8byte address) and the 2nd thread reads the pointer, who's 1st 4bytes are updated and last 4bytes are outdated ?

Using a 64bit machine

Comment: Eh? An 8-byte address on a 32 bits machine? What weird architecture is that? Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: This question is architecture-specific.  Are you using x86 or something else?

Comment: yeah, i am using x86_64